# Conjecture: An interesting concurrency concerning incircles

Tags: euclidean-geometry, triangles

**Conjecture:** Choose any point $P$ in the interior of the incircle of triangle $ABC$, and from the points of tangency, $D$, $E$, and $F$, draw lines through $P$ intersecting the incircle a second time at points $K$, $L$, and $M$, respectively. Then the straight lines $AK$, $BL$, and $CM$ are concurrent (in the picture at $Q$).

[image]

I would be particularly interested in a synthetic proof for this conjecture. It seems that the condition that $P$ lies in the interior of the incircle is not necessary. But a proof for this case would be sufficient for me.

I had already another post with nearly the same title, where I forgot to pose the question, the missing proof. So in this version it is clearer for the reader and maybe the chances better to get a solution.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: FYI: I've been able to verify this with some brute force coordinate-bashing in *Mathematica*. Intervening steps got pretty hairy, though.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an outline of a solution in [barycentric coordinates](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BarycentricCoordinates.html), leaving out all of the algebraic manipulation (performed by *Mathematica*):

Let $P$ (which need not lie in the incircle's interior) have barycentric coordinates $u:v:w$. That is, suppose we can write
$$P = \frac{u A + v B + w C}{u+v+w}$$

Let $D'$, $E'$, $F'$, be the "other" points of intersection of $\overleftrightarrow{PD}$, $\overleftrightarrow{PE}$, $\overleftrightarrow{PF}$ with the incircle. Defining
$$\alpha := \frac12\angle A \qquad \beta := \frac12\angle B \qquad \gamma :=\frac12\angle C$$ the barycentric coordinates of these points are
$$
\begin{align}
D'&= 2 \tan\alpha \left(\frac{\cos^2\beta}{v}+\frac{\cos^2\gamma}{w} \right)^2:
 \frac{\cos^2\beta \sin2\beta}{v^2}:
 \frac{\cos^2\gamma \sin2\gamma}{w^2} \\[4pt]
E'&= \frac{\cos^2\alpha \sin2\alpha}{u^2} : 2 \tan\beta \left(\frac{\cos^2\gamma}{w}+\frac{\cos^2\alpha}{u} \right)^2:
 \frac{\cos^2\gamma \sin2\gamma}{w^2} \\[4pt]
F'&= \frac{\cos^2\alpha \sin2\alpha}{u^2} : \frac{\cos^2\beta \sin2\beta}{v^2} : 2 \tan\gamma \left(\frac{\cos^2\alpha}{u}+\frac{\cos^2\beta}{v} \right)^2
\end{align}$$
Lines $\overleftrightarrow{AD'}$ and $\overleftrightarrow{BE'}$ meet at a point $P'$ with these barycentric coordinates

$$P' = \frac{\cos^2\alpha \sin2\alpha}{u^2} : 
\frac{\cos^2\beta \sin2\beta}{v^2} : 
\frac{\cos^2\gamma \sin2\gamma}{w^2}$$

The symmetry of these coordinates with respect to the elements of the triangle guarantees that $P'$ also lies on $\overleftrightarrow{CF'}$. It is indeed a point of concurrency. $\square$

Answer (score 3):

This is a well-known lemma, called Steinbart's Lemma if I recall correctly. Fairly straightforward by trig Ceva. Let $d$ be the diameter of the incircle. Note that
$$\sin \angle ECM = \sin \angle MEC \cdot \frac{EM}{MC} = \frac{EM}{d} \cdot \frac{EM}{MC} = \frac{EM^2}{d\cdot MC}.$$
Similarly,
$$\sin \angle MCD = \frac{MD^2}{d\cdot MC},$$
hence
$$\frac{\sin\angle ECM}{\sin \angle MCD} = \frac{EM^2}{MD^2}.$$
Multiplying this and two analogous equalities we obtain
$$\frac{\sin\angle ECM}{\sin \angle MCD}\cdot \frac{\sin\angle DBL}{\sin \angle LBF}\cdot \frac{\sin\angle FAK}{\sin \angle KAE} = \frac{EM^2}{MD^2}\cdot \frac{DL^2}{LF^2}\cdot \frac{FK^2}{KE^2}$$
which equals $1$ because $DK$, $EL$, $FM$ are concurrent. Therefore, by trig Ceva, $AK$, $BL$, $CM$ are concurrent.

Comment: Thank you very much for this beautiful solution and for telling me that this phenomenon has already a name (Steinbart's lemma).